# Refactoring Angular 4 http calls in service and containing errors

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm not completely up on the rxjs stuff, so this may well be simply a gap in my knowledge.

I want to refactor some of my http stuff out into a service.  Currently I have this...

```
this.http.get<LicenseKeyAndUsageModel>('api/license').subscribe(data => {
    this.licenseKeyAndUsage = data;
}, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    if (error.status !== 404) {
        //omitted for brevity, essentially notifies of unknown error.
    }
});
```

To clarify, if 404 is returned, it means there is no existing license key, which is fine as my local variable is never set and everyone's happy.

However, now I want to refactor it out into a service.  Most examples I see show returning the 'get' and let the caller subscribe to the result.

```
return this.http.get<LicenseKeyAndUsageModel>('api/license');
```

Sounds good.

What I don't understand is how to contain the error within the service so the caller either gets a value, or null.  Therefore I can simply assign the result to a local variable again, and let data binding do the rest.

I have seen some examples for similar stuff suggesting passing a callback in, to map into the subscribe CompletionObserver, but that doesn't smell good to me.

I suspect the answer might be in using map and catch, but I can't use the HttpErrorResponse with catch which seems a shame...

```
return this.http.get<LicenseKeyAndUsageModel>('api/license')
      .map(data => { return data; })
      .catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {

      });
```

(.catch line is not allowed, incorrect signature)

Waiting for the obvious answer :)

Comment: What you might want to consider is to extend the http class for your own purposes. You can then trap the error codes you want and pass the rest forward.

Comment: @PeterS In that case, an [interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses) might be a better way to go - I believe this is the recommended approach when using `HttpClient`.

Comment: An interceptor seems like a lot, just to trap a known status code returned from a REST-like service?

Comment: Its yet another solution and probably the best one in your case. What you will find is that you will re-use it for other issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you receive a TypeScript error about an incorrect signature is because your implementation of `catch` needs to return a new `Observable`. With what you've shown, the problem is actually your `void` return type.

In order to rethrow the error, you can use [`Observable.throw`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-throw), e.g.:

```
return Observable.throw(err);
```

Otherwise, when you want to ignore the error, you can use something like [`Observable.empty`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-empty), e.g.:

```
return Observable.empty();
```

To use `Observable.empty`, you might need to add the following:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';
```

If you want to return something different when using `catch`, you can use [`Observable.of`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-of). e.g.:

```
return Observable.of(null); // Or...
return Observable.of(/* Create your own LicenseKeyAndUsageModel here */);
```

The value used in `Observable.of` will be passed on through, shielding your subscribers from the fact that an error even occurred in the first place.

And again, to use `Observable.of`, you might need to add the following:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

Comment: You're correct, thank you, in that if I return Observable.Empty, I avoid the incorrect signature issue.  But now I'm definitely not following the rxjs stuff.  If I return the original 'get', the caller receives an Observable to subscribe to, therefore preserving the async nature, but returning the data in the map call means I'm just returning the object... so now I've got the map part wrong...

Answer (score 0):

for error handling if I understand your question correctly you could do this.

whatever your method is called, on subscription do the following.

```
const myResponse = someHttpService.getLicenseAndModel().subscribe(result => {
  return result,
  return error,
  return complete});
```

Comment: The whole point here is to try and trap the 'error' within the service... I'm not sure I'm following, but it looks like yours just passes it straight out again.

Comment: There isn’t a way to trap it as far as I see, consider a promise instead how would you trap an error?

Answer (score 0):

Using `.catch` is perfectly good solution. What you miss here is that `error` is of type `any`. This is why typescript complains about incorrect signature.

```
return this.http.get('api/license')
  //.map(data => { return data; }) //this is not needed, 
  // you may transform JSON string to actual object here:
  .map(response => response.json())
  .catch((error: any) => {
    // Be aware, that error may be something different than HttpResponse (for example instance of Error or even string).
    // For example, if .json() above would fail, you will get instance of Error class (the one built in JS engine).
    // You may cast error to desired class here.
    if(error instanceof HttpResponse && (error as HttpResponse).status == 404) {
      // Handle this error as you wish here.
    }
    return Observable.throw(error);
  });
```

Please also remember that `Http` service returns cold `Observable`. This means, that HTTP request is not made until you subscribe to returned observable.

**References**:
`HttpResponse` docs: 
https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse

The way how `.catch` operator is added:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/add/operator/catch.ts#L10

Actual definition of `.catch`:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/catch.ts#L64

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, you may just want to change your design.  A 404 error typically doesn't mean the server didn't find data, it means you are unauthorized to access the given url.  Why wouldn't you simply return null?

Maybe I'm not fully understanding your question?

Comment: Not to be blunt, but 404 is literally the Not found http status code. http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

Comment: Ha!  Was dealing with an auth (401) issue on my end when I wrote that, doh!  Coding while decaffeinated.

What I thought you were saying was that your server side code was querying a DB for a license, but was throwing a 404 instead of just returning null or an empty response when one isn't found, which seemed odd to me.  404 typically means the url does not exist.